# A cashier has only pennies, nickels, and quarters.

Tags: combinatorics

A cashier has only pennies, nickels, and quarters. When I asked him to break
a $1 bill he gave me 25 coins. Do you think the cashier made a counting mistake?

So I can solve this problem just by listing out the possible combinations. The cashier did make a mistake, but short of listing all the outcomes, I can't think of a way to know for sure. I'm just wondering if there is a more elegant solution. Maybe something with parity.

Comment: Try writing a system of equations in the variables p, n, and q, and see if you can get a contradiction.

Comment: The suggestion for a contradiction is what I needed to think about. Thanks I think that I got this now!

Comment: @acdude91: parity is a good way of thinking about it. Each time the cashier gives you a penny or a nickel or a quarter your return flips from an odd number of cents to an even number of cents. So you are going to need an even number of coins to get to $\$1$ and $25$ isn't even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p,n,q$ be the number of pennies, nickels, and quarters.  Then we want $$p+n+q=25\quad\&\quad p+5n+25q=100$$ Subtracting the first from the second shows that $4n+24q=75$.    But the left hand is even and the right hand is odd.

If you are used to modular arithmetic, you can just work $\pmod 2$ in which case the first equation reads $p+n+q\equiv 1$ and the second reads $p+n+q\equiv 0$.